# Java selenium google pages click

Tags: java

With Java selenium, I can type something on google and search, but I cannot click on the site I want in the search results. I tried all xpath formats but it didn't work. Do we need to use another code here?

Comment: Hi, can you add more info like the code are you trying? And also the html code of the item you want to click?

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
package tests;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import selenium.ChromeDriverSetup;

public class GooglSearchTest extends ChromeDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<WebElement> resultLinks = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
        String mySearchString = "fantomas wiki";
        
        // wrapped driver init in custom ChromeDriverSetup class
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get("https://www.google.cz");
        WebElement acceptBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("L2AGLb"));
        acceptBtn.click();
        
        WebElement searchInput = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchInput.sendKeys(mySearchString);
        
        // there are two sumbit buttons of same name, let's pick the visible one
        List<WebElement> searchBtns = driver.findElements(By.name("btnK"));
        for (WebElement searchBtn: searchBtns) {
            Point p = searchBtn.getLocation();
            if (p.getX() > 0 && p.getY() > 0) {
                searchBtn.click();
                break;
            }
        }

        // div for each result
        List<WebElement> searchResultDivs = driver.findElements(By.className("yuRUbf"));
        for (WebElement searchResultDiv: searchResultDivs) {
            // get first a tag of the div
            resultLinks.add(searchResultDiv.findElement(By.tagName("a")));
        }
        
        // clicking link of first result
        resultLinks.get(0).click();
        
        // page changed
        System.out.println("Current URL: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        System.out.println("Current title: " + driver.getTitle());
        
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 107.0.5304.62 (1eec40d3a5764881c92085aaee66d25075c159aa-refs/branch-heads/5304@{#942}) on port 20110
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Lis 29, 2022 11:10:07 DOP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Current URL: https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantomas
Current title: Fantomas – Wikipedie
```